# How can I change Model values from within Django Admin's response_change?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I have added a custom button to my **Django Admin** by overriding `change_form.html`. I'd like this button to read a `site_url` field from the model itself, scape that site, and then programatically change the model's form fields (without saving it).. so it can be reviewed and corrected before saving.

I have successfully got my button to print the object by overriding `response_change`. I can also pre-populate the template by using extra_context by overriding change_view.

```py
def response_change(self, request, obj):
    if '_scrape-site' in request.POST:
      print(obj)
      return HttpResponseRedirect(".")
    return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

I'd like to be able to enter a `site_url` and scrape it using `requests/bs4 or scrapy`, and then return those values into the `change_form` in the Title and Summary text boxes (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbskD.png). Is that possible?

Comment: This is probably best handled by a custom view that returns a redirect to the admin add view. You can use GET parameters to set initial values for fields in the add view `/admin/app/model/add/?title=whatever`

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington, this strategy worked well for me. I created a new custom admin view, put an `input form` on that view to collect the `site_url`, and then on `request.POST` I scraped the site and sent redirected to the add view with a urlencoded query string.